# pkg-config and OSX 10.8, proper PKG_CONFIG_PATH? Missing .pc files?

Tags: macos, build, makefile, osx-mountain-lion, pkg-config

I installed pkg-config with homebrew in OSX.  I'm not sure what I should set my PKG_CONFIG_PATH to?  Should it be a combination of /usr/include and /usr/local/include?  Even if I use one or the other, I get an error about there not being any .pc files, which I take it would contain info used by pkg-config?  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Help appreciated.

```
$ pkg-config --libs libxml2  
Package libxml2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.  
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml2.pc'  
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable  
No package 'libxml2' found
```

Update:
So maybe I'm asking two different questions.  I just curled gsl and ran through the ./configure && make && sudo make install.  And with an empty $PKG_CONFIG_PATH I actually got a hit with:

```
pkg-config --libs gsl  
-L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

But listing /usr/local/lib shows the gsl libs but no .pc files.  How come pkg-config works for custom installed packages in OSX but not default installed ones???

Answer (score 18):

`echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`

to test with say glib:

```
brew install glib && pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0
```

should get you the goods:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.34.3/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.34.3/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.2/include  -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.34.3/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.2/lib -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a clarification comment to Nick's answer above, but that is the correct set of paths you need, I have tried with success using homebrew on osx 10.9.1.

If you want this to work with a GUI application such as an IDE, you need to add that path to `/etc/launchd.conf`.

See the following stack overflow comment: 
[Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)